# A* - Graph Traversal Heuristic

Tags: algorithm, graph, a-star

I have a graph that represents a city. I know the location of places of interest (nodes, which have a Importance value), the location of the hotel I'm staying in, how the nodes are connected, the traversal time between them and have acess to latitude and longitude. There are no issues converting from time to distance and vice-versa.

The objective is to tour the city, maximizing the importance per day but limiting one day of travel to 10 hours. A day begins and ends at the hotel. I have a working A* algorithm that chooses the lowest value but with no heuristic yet, which I guess makes it a BB for now. With that in mind:

- Since I have access to Lat/Long, my first stab at an heuristic, while
  only dealing with times, would be the distance as the crow flies
  between a node and the hotel. Would this be an admissible heuristic?
  It gives me the shortest possible distance and time, so it wouldn't
  overestimate.

Now let's say the Importance of a node is between 1-4. In order to factor it in, one idea could be g(neighbor) = g(current) + (edge_cost / Importance^2). Assuming this would be valid (if not, why?):

- But now the heuristic values would be in a different unit. Could a solution to this simply be give the Hotel Importance = 1? If the value is the same, will it still be admissible? EDIT: I think this will end up giving me problems because of the difference in scale.
- I still have to restrict the total amount of time. Should each node keep track of the total time spent, in order to compare to the limit, plus the g() and h() values, because of the different units?

And finally:

- Since I have to start and end in the same node, what comes to mind is to explore a node and should I find the hotel see if I still have time to explore the neighbors instead of going back. However, if I still have time to expand to one more node, but time runs out and I can't get to the hotel from there, I'm assuming I'll have to backtrack to the parent.
- I can't help but see similarities to the knapsack problem. Even though I have to use A*, is there any lesson I can take from it?
- Must my heuristic be consistent in this case? If so, why?

By the way, the purpose here is pathfinding first, optimizations second.

Comment: This is actually a generalization of [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) - which is NP-Complete. The problem with A* - is it does not support restriction on the route itself, it is only designed to find shortest path from a source to a set of targets, and this is not your case (not without modifications anyway).

Comment: And I'm responsible for those modifications. I'm pretty much stuck with A* for this one. Hence all the questions.

Comment: It is weird to me to use A* for this task, it seems much more of an optimization problem than shortest path problem - so Genethic Algorithms or Hill Climbing for example seems much more appropriate here.

Comment: It's a project. There is actually this same theme but with other algorithms. But this is what I have to work with.

Comment: As have already been said, this sounds like using a hammer to screw a screw. A* will tell to the shortest path between point A and B, right, and that is the Manhattan distance if you could fly, so that is already known, you already know how to get from point A to B. If the problem is to either create a circle from A to A and path through as many sights as possible with a max bound, then its the TSP problem, or picking events to put on your list, with a max bound, then the Knapsack, in neither of them would a A* be of any help.

Comment: Then let me ask this: Since the project is "Implementation of a Tourist Guide using Pathfinding Algorithms", is there any algorithm in pathfinding that can be useful. I'm currently looking into other StackOverflow questions about using A* for TSP.

Comment: Scratch that last one, and let me ask this: is there a informed search method to better handle this?

Comment: My feeling is that this question has too many sub-questions to be broadly useful. My suggestion is that you try to break it up.

Comment: I'm unclear on how I would recognize a correct solution, so I have these questions:  
Is a solution several days of touring with overall optimality, or one? ... What is an optimal solution?  One that crams the most importance points into 10 hours? ... Can we count distances between sites as times?  If not, how do we convert?  Also, do we assume 0 time spent at a site; if not, how much time?

Answer (score 1):

This actually looks like a combination of the travelling salesman problem (TSP) and knapsack problem (KP). It's KP in this respect: the knapsack capacity is 10 (for total hours available in a day) and the locations are the items. The item value equals the location value. The item weight is equal to the time it takes to travel to the location (plus the location's portion of the trip back to the hotel). The challenge arises from the fact that an item's weight is unknown until you solve the optimal tour through the selected locations--enter the TSP and Pathfinding.

One approach might be to use a pathfinding algorithm (e.g. A*, Bellman–Ford, or Dijkstra's algorithm) primarily to compute a distance matrix between each node. The distance matrix can then be leveraged while solving the TSP portion of the problem: finding a tour through the locations and using the total time as the weight.

The next step is up to you. If you are looking for an approximate solution, many heuristics exist for both TSP and KP: See [Christofides TSP Heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm), or the [Minimum TSP](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node104.html) and [Maximum Knapsack](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node211.html) entries at the [Compendium of NP Optimization problems](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/wwwcompendium.html).

If on the other hand you seek an optimal solution, you may be out of luck. Still I recommend you find a copy of *Graph Theory. An Algorithmic Approach* by Nicos Christofides (ISBN-13: 978-0121743505). It provides heuristics for early backtracking in a Depth-First-Search that expedite the search for optimal solutions to several NP-Complete problems.